# Why will plymouth not update?

Tags: kernel, gentoo, systemd, bootsplash

I admit I don't update my kernel very often.  I used to everytime a stable release of `sys-kernel/gentoo-sources` came out so I'm very adept at doing it.  This last weekend I attempted to update from 3.12.13 to 3.14.14.  Over this past weekend, I was able to update with one MAJOR ANNOYANCE.  More on that after my configuration:

1. Kernel: 3.12.13-gentoo
2. Initial RAM Disk Creator: sys-kernel/genkernel-next-58
3. Video Drivers: uvesafb for frame buffer and x11-drivers/nvidia-drivers-343.22 for XOrg Server/KDE.  I need the nvidia-drivers for Eve Online.  AFAIK, nouveau won't work with Eve.
4. Init System: sys-apps/systemd-215-r3

---

**TL;DR**.  See bolded Question

After Setting the Appropriate Settings in `/etc/genkernel.conf`(I set PLYMOUTH to YES, PLYMOUTH_THEME to tribar), I used `eselect kernel set` to set the kernel soft link to 3.14.14 and used `genkernel all` to build everything.  I ran `grub2-mkconfig`, I rebooted and realized I built the wrong network driver(ath5k instead of ath9k), and that I hated tribar.  Saturday morning, I replaced tribar with solar, removed and replaced ath5k with ath9k, reran `genkernel all`/`grub2-mkconfig`and rebooted...

---

To my odd surprise I received 2 ASCII Squares, and a Percentage Sign repeating 3 times instead of the solar theme.  I double checked my terminal commands and reran them in sequence with the same result.  I double checked the conf files too.  `/etc/plymouth/plymouthd.conf` contained solar, same with the `/etc/genkernel.conf` file.  I ran `genkernel initramfs` in KDE/kterm so I could scrollback, and I saw the solar theme files copied into the RAM Disk.

The oddest part of all is that even though all the files are copied into the RAM Disk correctly, if I put tribar in all the appropriate files again, plymouth will show tribar correctly.  2 Ascii boxes and 1 percentage sign equals 1 of the tribars.  As such, **why is plymouth still showing the tribar theme when I told it to use solar?**  I know this should work correctly because I still have my old kernel that I set up to use the spinfinity theme when I first switched over to grub 2 and systemd.  If I boot with it, I see the spinfinity theme.

On a side note, I do see a warning during boot on the new kernel about systemd not being able to write to /tmp because /tmp isn't empty.  Could this be part of the problem?

Signed,
*Experienced but Frustrated*

Comment: have you tried unpacking your ramdisk and verifying that the solar files are really there? (I know it said it copied them, but maybe there was a problem.)

Comment: @strugee I've got Genkernel-next's logging set to 5, which is the highest level of verbose, but I'll check that tonight...

Comment: Not familiar with gentoo mechanisms, but you need to set the theme and also rebuild your initrd. Assuming gentoo also uses dracut, please have a look at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/plymouth

Maybe you should move your manually-edited initrd away, and recreate one from scratch via dracut.